# Azure Websites Deployment Task Failed

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am hosting a website on Azure Websites, and starting around 10AM CST today, I have been unable to deploy for the following reason

> Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("waws-prod-chX-XXX.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

On top of that the site keeps giving a 502 gateway error (after 5 minutes), BUT the Azure dashboard shows everything is up: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

I use the Standard Mode on a Small VM which I share between 3 other sites, the other sites are all fine, and I can publish to them, just not this one. They all have the same web deployment server.

Comment: I'm facing a lot of problems today with Windows Azure. I can't perform a swap between my staging and production environment. I hope that they fix everything as soon as possible.

Comment: It looks like it isn't just this deployment environment either, a free site hosted in another location is also having the same issue. But the dashboard doesn't reflect any issues.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I experienced the same error, and did not see anything wrong in the console. Then right as the hour turned over, I was able to do it again.

There must be some setting that only allows X number of WebDeploy resources to be used per hour.